Reschedule a task earlier if the originally scheduled on fails
I have a spring scheduler which have one scheduled task with cron trigger of every 24 hours. when the task fails for any reason it waits until next 24 hours to trigger again. I want to reschedule the task for next hour if it fails the first time and so on. @Retryable wont fit my requirement as i don't want service to sleep for an hour until the next retry.  How can i achieve this. Want to have scheduled task triggered by corns and reschedule same task on failure. Basically adding another task i would believe to run same thing. It won't be exact reschedule because once this task is success the second time i want to continue with the first schedule which is every 24 hours.
For now just using @Scheduled(cron = "${scheduledBatchJob.daily.cronExpression}")
to achieve the scheduled task
